# ArcMap 10.5 Generating Seamlines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.5

[image]

[image: Everything was left default and I generated it in ArcCatalog]

I have a mosaic data set that contains around 60 rasters. I generated a seam line for them and it worked great.

However, the only issue is that I can only view the seam line at a scale less than 1:12,000.

I am needing it about 10x larger. At the larger scales it looks as if there was never a seam line generated.

Comment: How did you generate the line ? Can you post a screen shot ?

Comment: I added a screenshot and everything was left to default

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by rebuilding the overview, pyramids and statistics.